# RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an application written in electron and nodejs that I am trying to run. It uses the module [portscanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portscanner) to check for an open port in a particular range:

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
  console.log("Free port: " + port)

})
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536
    at assertPort (internal/net.js:17:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
```

Even though the range I have is clearly less than 65536 and greater than 0.

Looking online, it seems to be an error in node v6 (I have v6.5.0). I am new to nodejs, and would greatly appreciate any help regarding how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Why? Just bind to port number zero. There is no need to scan for it, and there is no guarantee that the port you found by scanning will still be available when you go to use it. Don't do this.

Comment: If you absolutely want to bind in this range, just make a loop and try to bind until it works. No need to use a module for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was planning to do that if I found no solution at all. @EJP I was initially getting a lot of ADDRINUSE errors, and I had to manually kill the port before restarting the application to make it work. So, I figured this might be a neat solution.

Comment: It isn't. It is pointless. Listening at a random port doesn't require anything but a zero in the right place, but then how are you going to tell the clients which port it is?

Comment: The port number will go straight to the mitm proxy module thats being used inside the application. Its the port at which the proxy will listen. I kinda don't understand why its pointless though, how can I prevent the ADDRINUSE errors if they occur, even with a random port I choose.

Comment: They occur for the reason I gave in my first comment. There is a timing-window problem between scanning for a free port and trying to use it. Just use port zero. I said that too. You can find out what port was allocated via `getsockname()` or whatever its equivalent in your language is.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you are getting ADDRINUSE or similar errors, make sure your program is exiting cleanly.  You could also try the `kill` command or use pm2.

But if you really need to look for a port, can you post the rest of the code?  It says the error is in the server.listen.  Are you sure you started listening *after* the findAPortNotInUse came back?

Comment: 1. He is not getting E_ADDRINUSE errors. 2. A question is not an answer.

Comment: He very well may be getting that, which is why he is doing the port finding thing.  There isn't a way to answer for sure without the question, but I am reasonably sure that one of my comments/questions will solve his issue.  You simply dismissed his question.

Comment: He is getting 'port number out of range'. Nothing to do with 'address in use' whatsoever. And I didn't 'just dismiss his question', I provided the correct solution. As opposed to mere guesswork.

Comment: Actually yes, I was getting ADDRINUSE errors. And just after finding an open port, the code goes into an mitmproxy, the node-thin module.

Comment: And yes, definitely "after" as far as I can gather.

Answer (score 2):

> It's an issue with newer versions of node.

https://github.com/FWeinb/nodeshot/issues/11

It was also raised as an [issue](https://github.com/FWeinb/electron-screenshot-service/issues/19) on the electron project.

For quickly handle it you can also use `try.....catch`

Comment: Note that the author says he isn't going to fix it, and that the workaround is exactly what already recommended in my comment. A completely pointless tool.

Comment: Yes, you are right in your place he is not going to fix it. I just give him reference where he can check the exact issue while working with `electron`

Answer (score 0):

It might be coz the **localhost** is not defined with the *required syntax* in the **"hosts"** file of the system.

The file can be located @:

=>            etc/hosts

(above file for ***linux***)

or

=>            c:\ **Windows** \System32\Drivers\ **etc** \ **hosts**

(above file for **Windows**)

i.e. file has some wrong input.

So, Try replacing everything in that file with the text below as this is the default text that was always there in *hosts* file when it worked fine:

127.0.0.1   localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1             localhost

fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Answer (score 0):

Better first convert it into a Number then use it.

something like that.
parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10) || 3000

Answer (score 0):

I also get same error when I try 8000 which is in the range of 0 - 65536

- I sent request like this "http:127.0.0.1:8000status" instead of "http:127.0.0.1:8000/status"
- once check the "/"